# Running batch command on an executable using python

Tags: python, string, batch-file, sysinternals

I'm using this code to start the batch file but

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\Documents and Settings\Zha\Desktop\Strings\strings.exe ")
```

the strings.exe running a batch command when you open it from cmd, like this:

```
strings -q "C:\Documents and Settings\Zha\Desktop\folder\*"
```

and I need to run it from python. Possible way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

handle = Popen(['strings', '-q', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Zha\\Desktop\\folder\\*'], stdout=PIPE)

while handle.poll() is None:
    print(handle.stdout.readline())
handle.stdout.close()
```

Comment: `shell=True` could be a risk!

Comment: Does the normally-equivalent `Popen(['strings', '-q', 'C:\...\*'], stdout=PIPE)` work? If so, that's a better answer.

Comment: @pss It's not actually likely to be a risk as a *constant* is being passed to `Popen`, but it's a lot like `eval`: *don't* use it unless you *have* to. And you *never* have to (with the exception of giving an interface directly to the shell, which is rare to say the least).

Comment: Will correct it in a bit.

Comment: I omit 'shell=True' and it worked

Comment: @TheGameDoctor It works both with and without, it's just a matter of how to input the command. `shell=True` can take a single string while alse` needs a list if i'm not mistaken. Also the eval thing.